# Compile error UWP only in Release

Tags: compilation, uwp, release

Hello guys so I've released a beta version of an app that I was about to release to Microsoft store and I was starting to build for x86 when I got this error

```
Error       ILT0005: 'C:\Users\User\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.1\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Users\user\Source\Repos\PeaCoreUWP\PeaCoreUWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\appname.rsp"' returned exit code 1 PeaCoreUWP
```

I've tried almost anything reinstalled windows, visual studio, did a repair nothing worker at all. Can someone please point me to a solution of this problem? 
My dev environment is Visual Studio 2017  last update. Also debug build works perfectly fine for any of the build types ARM, x64,x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either delete this or leave it here but I've managed to find a solution to my problem. It turns out that the compilation error was caused by a dependency on the XAML controls that I use (Syncfusion), for some reason when I add the full assembly to the project reference It throws an error. The solution is to reference the specific control assemblies that you're using (example would be reference of grid, tabcontrol, navigation etc). Hope this helps someone in the future. Should have checked that before posting but what's done has already past so thank you for reading and I wish you good day/night.

Comment: By the way app containing name Beta is now not allowed in store publish. Not sure you can check, you should register a app name in store not inc. Name "Beta".  Previously i receive a message (for individual) your not allow to publish beta version please complete your app then submit it.